# Rings as chatzitzahs for bread, mikvah, washing

Tags: women, netilat-yadayim-washing, mikvah-ritual-bath, jewelry, chatzitzah

A woman who makes challah in her rings may leave them on for al netilas yadayim. ([Source](http://halachafortodaycom.blogspot.com/2013/02/archives-hilchos-netilas-yadayim.html?m=1).) Does this mean she could leave them on for mikvah, too? Why or why not?

(I understand the answer is almost certainly no, at least in practice. But I would appreciate a technical explanation for that.)

Related: 
[Remove rings to wash?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12793/remove-rings-to-wash)

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22185/759

Comment: You missed out Lulav.  There it is mentioned that one (referring to a man) has to take rings off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Halochakli it is permitted if a chatzitza  covers less than half the body (or heir) and it does not bother most of the woman like her (that have her profession)

**But the minhag is lohathila for mikva no chatzitza at all,**

( bidieved if like above (halochakly permited) then OK, (if went home already even more lenient (ask a Rabbi) so that people should not say bad things  )

As to can see this brought in the beginning of [this](http://www.yoatzot.org/taharat-hamishpacha/?id=537)

Even the source you bring seems to permit it for hand washing also only bdieved (after the fact)

From the sources @kouty brought below it seems that rings are thing that are removed, so unless you are part of a type of women that does not remove them ever you halochakli need to remove them

But the source you brought ([siman 127](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1081&st=&pgnum=97&hilite=)) hints that most women now do not knead dough so do not need to remove halochakli, but Baker's need to even if they do not since most Baker's do

Comment: The answer references "the minhag". The Jewish people are not a single homogeneous group, which group(s) have this custom?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38427/discussion-between-kouty-and-hazoriz

Comment: @hazoriz Lots and lots and lots of women still knead dough by hand. Thanks for the strong answer.